# how to handle form data without containing file inputs in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am currently using express and multer for handling form data with file inputs in nodejs .How can i handle a simple form data object that only contains text inputs in nodejs?.currently I am using below code to retrieve the form data contents.

```
app.post("/reactLogin",function(req,res) {
        var uploads = multer({
    }).single();
    uploads(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        var email=req.body

    })

})
```

is this correct?is there any other way to handle the form data containing only text inputs?

Answer (score -1):

you should give a try to the `bodyparser` npm packages, which acts as a middleware of express applications to give you an access to all for form's data at `req.body`

Comment: i am already using it .but when using req.body it returns an empty object.It works only if i wrote in the above manner.